# How to get the automatically generated ID for an actionview form helper 'number_field' input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

I'm trying to retrieve an ID that is being generated for an input via the number_field actionview form helper.

I am updating some existing code which has the following input without a label:

```
<%= item_form.number_field :quantity, :min => 0 %>
```

When I try adding a label like this:

`<%= label_tag :quantity, "Foo" %>`

the 'for' attribute of the label tag comes out as 'quantity' whereas the id of the number field comes out as 'order_line_items_attributes_0_quantity'

As there may be several of these fields on the page, I cannot have a static ID.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= item_form.label :quantity, "Foo" %>` should generate "for" attribute with the right ID.